# ElasticSearch not failing but returning incorrect results

Tags: ajax, elasticsearch, amplifyjs

I switched to POST searches using ajax in my application so I can start using the date range. However it seems no matter what I post it keeps returning the first 10 results in my index. The true results are in the 30k range.

```
    amplify.request.define("searchPostRequest", "ajax", {
        url: "http://leServer:9200/people/person/_search",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        contentType: 'application/json'
    });
    self.advancedSearchPostQuery = {
        query: {
           term: {
               locationNumber:479
            }
        }
    };
    console.log(self.advancedSearchPostQuery);
    amplify.request({
        resourceId: "searchPostRequest",
        data: JSON.stringify(self.advancedSearchPostQuery),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.hits.hits.length);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more debugging I found that the request was being sent as a GET even though I had explicitly set it to post.  Moving the data type to json, from jsonp let the request be sent as a POST, which resolved the issue.   However this causes an issue in IE where the request is not sent at all due to the request being sent to another domain.

```
    amplify.request.define("searchPostRequest", "ajax", {
        url: "http://leServer:9200/people/person/_search",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is your actual code, your problem might simply be that your 
`advancedSearchPostQuery` isn't valid JSON.

You need to apply quotes:

```
advancedSearchPostQuery = {
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "locationNumber": 479
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm not sure if you need to `stringify` the object, but I'm not familiar with amplifyJS, so double check on that as well if amplifyjs is expecting an object or a string.

If that doesn't help check if your query returns the correct results when running from command line through curl.