# jsonp being sent as GET

Tags: jquery, ajax, elasticsearch

I opened another post last week because my elastic search was not returning accurate results see, [ElasticSearch post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14405886/elasticsearch-not-failing-but-returning-incorrect-results)

Basically what was happening was that when I am using jsonp, the request is not actually being sent as a GET request instead of a POST request. Below is the jsonp request.   When I use json, it actually gets sent as a POST.

```
   amplify.request.define("searchPostRequest", "ajax", {
        url: "http://leServer:9200/people/person/_search",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        contentType: 'application/json'
    });
```

Anyone know how I can force jsonp to be sent as a POST request?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post data to JsonP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699277/post-data-to-jsonp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not make a JSONP call to a different domain or same domain with a POST since JSONP works by adding a script tag to the page. It is not making an XMLHttpRequest.

If you want to post data and it is the same domain, just make a normal POST ajax call to the server and return JSON.

If it is a cross domain call: If you control the other domain and you only care about modern day browsers you can use [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), If not, you would have to use a proxy on your server to make the post request. Both of these solutions would also be making a JSON call, not JSONP.

Comment: the odd thing is that both machines are in fact on the same domain, however IE does not send the request.  Chrome has no issue though.

Comment: @zmanc If that's the case, why resort to `jsonp` in the first place then?

Comment: @zmanc note that a different port or protocol will count as a different domain. Ie `https://mysite.com:80` counts as a different domain to `http://mysite.com:81`

Comment: JSONP still uses a GET request. It does not matter if it is on a different domain or same.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan,  I think that might be the final piece to the puzzle. So if I drop the port requirement in the request it should be able to function as expected?

Comment: You don't have to drop it (I assume you need it?), you need to ensure that both sites are on the same domain if possible.

Comment: @zmanc If both domains conform to the same-origin-policy you can make a standard POST request from one to the other. See [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) for clear and concise examples.